# Haskell: Can I use a where clause after a block with bind operators (>>=)?

Tags: syntax, haskell, monads

I have a very simple question. I'd like to use a where clause after a bloc of code that uses bind operators but I get a compilation error.

Here is a simple example:

```
main =
    putStrLn "where clause test:" >>
    return [1..10] >>= \list ->
    print list'
        where list' = reverse list -- test1.hs:5:28: Not in scope: `list'
```

I can use a let clause for list' as in

```
main =
    putStrLn "where clause test:" >>
    return [1..10] >>= \list ->
    let list' = reverse list -- works of course
    in print list'
```

but I'd really like it if I could use a where clause...

I also tried with do notation

```
main = do
    putStrLn "where clause test:"
    list <- return [1..10]
    print list'
        where list' = reverse list --test3.hs:5:30: Not in scope: `list'
```

Same problem. Can I use a where clause in these circumstances?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As ephemient explains, you can't use `where` clauses the way you do.

The error happens because  in this code:

```
main =
  return [1..10] >>= \list ->
  print list'
    where
      list' = reverse list
```

The `where`-clause is attached to the main function.

Here's that same function with more parentheses:

```
main = return [1..10] >>= (\list -> print list')
  where
    list' = reverse list
```

I think its fairly obvious why you get the "`out of scope`" error: The binding for `list` is deep inside the `main` expression, not something the `where` clause can reach.

What I usually do in this situation (and I've been bitten by the same thing a bunch of times). I simply introduce a function and pass the `list` as an argument.

```
main = do
  list <- return [1..10]
  let list' = f list
  print list'
  where
    f list = reverse list -- Consider renaming list,
                          -- or writing in point-free style
```

Of course, I imagine your actual code in the `f` function is a lot more that just `reverse` and that's why you want it inside a `where` clause, instead of an inline `let` binding. If the code inside the `f` function is very small, I'd just write it inside the `let` binding, and wouldn't go through the overhead of introducing a new function.

Comment: Thanks, your example with more parenthesis clears it up for me.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `let`-`in` is an expression, which can be used inside other expressions, while `where` can only be used on a (module|class|instance|GADT|...) declaration or a (function|pattern) binding.

From the Haskell 98 report on [declarations and bindings](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#patbind),

> *p* | *g<sub>1</sub>* `=` *e<sub>1</sub>*
>       | *g<sub>2</sub>* `=` *e<sub>2</sub>*
>       …
>       | *g<sub>m</sub>* `=` *e<sub>m</sub>*
>     `where {` *decls* `}`

is sugar for

> *p* `= let` *decls* `in`
>         `if` *g<sub>1</sub>* `then` *e<sub>1</sub>* `else`
>         `if` *g<sub>2</sub>* `then` *e<sub>2</sub>* `else`
>         …
>         `if` *g<sub>m</sub>* `then` *e<sub>m</sub>* `else error "Unmatched pattern"`

or, simplifying things by removing guards,

> *p* `=` *e* `where {` *decls* `}`

is sugar for

> *p* `= let` *decls* `in` *e*

in both function and pattern bindings.  This is true even when your *e* is a `do {`…`}` construct.

If you want to have a binding local to a particular subexpression within a larger expression, you need to use `let`-`in` (or simply `let` inside a `do`, but that's just sugar for `let`-`in`).

You can't even write

```
main = do
    putStrLn "where clause test: "
    list <- return [1..10]
    (print list' where list' = reverse list)
```

because "*e* `where {` *decls* `}`" is not a legal expression – `where` can only be used in declarations and bindings.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "where clause test: "
    list <- return [1..10]
    let list' = list'' where list'' = reverse list
    print list'
```

This is legal (if somewhat contrived).

Comment: why not just "let list' = reverse list"? in the last example?

Comment: Thanks, I should refer to the Haskell Report more often when I have fundamental questions about the language such as this.

Comment: @newacct: OP's question already includes that variant, which obviously works.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the where clause is only used in *local bindings*.  The inner part of a >>(=) binding statement is not a local binding (two different kinds of bindings in that sentence).

Compare with this:

```
main = f [1..10]

f list =
    putStrLn "where clause test:" >> print list'
        where list' = reverse list
```

You might want to refer to the [Haskell 98 syntax report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html) - not sure how much help it would be.

If I'm wrong, someone will certainly correct me, but I'm pretty sure you can't use a where clause at all in the style you've shown above.  `list` will never be in scope to a where clause unless it's a parameter to the function.

Comment: A lambda abstraction is an expression, not a declaration or binding, though it can bind new names...

Comment: Whoa, who -1'ed this?  I think it's correct, if not as complete as it could be.

Comment: it's not relevant. the OP wants to use "list", a result from the middle of a bunch of monadic computations; not a value that is from outside the monad